# Reset RadGrid to prior state after Rebind()

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, telerik-grid, radgrid

I am rebinding a Hierarchical radgrid after closing a custom edit/insert form using the below code and javascript. I would like to reset the state of the Grid as it was when the user clicked to edit a record. Currently all childgrids close up to the master.

What I want them to see...
[image: where I want the user to be after the Rebind()]

What they currently see...

[image: currently what they see]

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadAjaxManager manager = RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page);
    manager.ClientEvents.OnRequestStart = "onRequestStart";
    manager.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(manager, this.__rejectedBatchesRadGrid);
    manager.AjaxRequest += new RadAjaxControl.AjaxRequestDelegate(Manager_AjaxRequest);  

    if (!IsPostBack) {  }
}

protected void Manager_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
{
    this.__rejectedBatchesRadGrid.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.Clear();
    this.__rejectedBatchesRadGrid.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Clear();
    this.__rejectedBatchesRadGrid.Rebind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone still looking for an answer in the future here is [a link](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/grid/retain-expanded-selected-state-in-hierarchy-on-rebind.aspx) that I finally received from Telerik that accomplishes what I was trying to do.